# Identify a child element with a click event

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, dom

I have a similar code to this one in `ReactJS`:

```
<div onClick={(e) => testeFn(e)}>
   <p className="bg-primary">Test 1</p>
   <p className="bg-primary">Test 2</p>
   <p className="bg-primary">Test 3</p>
   <p className="bg-primary">Test 4</p>
</div>
```

I need to get the child element clicked in order to change its `background-color` to red, but only one of the elements must receive the background red each time, so, if I click on the first one, it'll be red, but if after that I click on the second element, it receives the bg red and the first one gets back to primary.

I did this:

```
const testeFn = e => {

    let children = e.currentTarget.children

    let childrenArray = Array.from(children)
}
```

My idea was to loop over `childrenArray` and extract each element, aim the one clicked and set its `bg` as red, but I don't know how to identify the one clicked, since the loop will return all of them. Maybe with the `index` it would be possible, but I don't know how.

I know that I could use a Bootstrap builtin navigation or even find some code on Google, but I really want to learn how to do that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I could come up with a solution inverting the logic, adding a step and using css to set the `bg` instead of Bootstrap.

I am still looping over the children elements, but rather than using the loop to identify the clicked element and set it as the selected one, I am setting all backgrounds with the original color, which is blue. After that I set the clicked element with a background red.

These steps ensure that all elements will have the bg blue, except the target one, since the first step will always set all elements with a background blue and the second one will set only the target element with a background red.

```
const testeFn = e => {

    let target = e.target
    let children = e.currentTarget.children
    let childrenArray = Array.from(children)

    childrenArray.map(child => {
        child.style.backgroundColor = 'blue'
        child.style.color = 'black'
    })
    
    target.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
    target.style.color = 'white'

}


<div onClick={(e) => testeFn(e)}>
   <p style={{backgroundColor: 'blue'}}>Test 1</p>
   <p style={{backgroundColor: 'blue'}}>Test 2</p>
   <p style={{backgroundColor: 'blue'}}>Test 3</p>
   <p style={{backgroundColor: 'blue'}}>Test 4</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do this is to use `closest()` (added eventlistener to make it work here)

```js
const testeFn = e => {
  let target = e.target.closest('.bg-primary'); 
  if (target) {
    // reset
    document.querySelectorAll('.bg-primary').forEach(el => {
       el.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    })

    // add to target
    target.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }
}

document.addEventListener('click', e => testeFn(e));
```

```html
<div id="test">
   <p class="bg-primary" style='background-color: blue'>Test 1</p>
   <p class="bg-primary" style='background-color: blue'>Test 2</p>
   <p class="bg-primary" style='background-color: blue'>Test 3</p>
   <p class="bg-primary" style='background-color: blue'>Test 4</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer may work, but I let clear that I am using React and you edited the code and gave me a html answer.

Comment: The function still works with react... You should be able to extract logic right ? 
You just need to call it in onClick={}